# Почему не выдаётся знак Скрытый талант?

Tags: поддержка, знаки

В условиях сказано "Нулевой рейтинг принятых ответов: более 5 и 20% от общего количества."

У меня  в stackoverflow-на-русском 8 таких ответов, а всего 28. Получается больше 28% (8/28).

Вроде бы по условиям подходит, но знака нет :(

Comment: В-первых, подозреваю, что 8 из 17, во-вторых, там вроде раньше минимальное количество было. А, стоп, более 5, написано же...

Comment: Ещё версия: у трёх ответов рейтинг +1-1, если нужно именно отсутствие голосов, то то получится 5/18.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тогда надо описание знака поменять, потому что по описанию моя статистика формально подходит

Comment: Похоже что подразумевается именно нулевой рейтинг (а не отсутствие голосов), но процент именно от принятых (не от общего количества) ответов: потому что имея [39](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A288409+is%3Aanswer+score%3A0+isaccepted%3Ayes) принятых ответов с нулевым рейтингом, знак я получил 4 дня назад - хотя если взять общее кол-во ответов 427, это всего лишь 9% (не заслужил)... а вот если считать процент только от принятых, коих у меня 185, то получается 21% и все сходится. **Короче**, имхо у тебя все ок, попробуй просто подождать пересчета данных :) оно может быть по таймеру

Comment: @yar85 Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по [этому ответу на Meta enSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261690/12506088), принятые ответы с нулевым рейтингом должны быть **возрастом от 10ти дней**, чтобы знак [Скрытый талант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/50/tenacious) был выдан:

> Yes, you need at least 6 answers that are accepted and still at 0 when they are at least 10 days old. They need to make up at least 20% of all your accepted answers (over 10 days old).

В твоем профиле я вижу пять новых (моложе 10 дней) ответов подходящих к критериям знака, и *без их учета* мы получаем такой расклад: 3 ответа с нулевым рейтингом из 4 принятых = 75%. Соотношение более чем соблюдено, а вот по количеству пока что недобор, надо ждать пока ответы "настоятся".
То есть, получается что нужно в течение следующих нескольких дней сдержать соотношение принятых ответов с нулевым рейтингом (к общему кол-ву принятых) выше отметки 20%, и тогда знак появится. Если два твоих "свежих" принятых ответа не выйдут из нуля, то вероятно что это случится уже завтра-послезавтра... если обновление данных тут происходит не раз в неделю по воскресеньям (что-то такое в комментах к западному ответу написано).

#### upd.:

Запилил [форк-обновление запроса "**How Unsung am I?**"](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1442947/how-unsung-am-i-count-answers-over-10-days-old) для относительно легкой проверки соблюдения условий знака (надо только ввести числовой ID участника, и нажать <kbd>Run Query</kbd>).

Comment: Конечно, не в тему, но как ты сделал "эффект кнопки" на словах `"Run Query"`?

Comment: @Anastasia, `<kbd>Run Query</kbd>`.